# Nodejs - Mocha, Chai multiple async testing

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai, node-async

Complete NodeJS testing noob here. Trying to individually test functions that are called through my API (meaning, rather than make an http request to a specific endpoint, which usually invokes several functions, which in turn make requests to different third party APIs, I want to test the functions themselves separately). The way they're called is I've built a class for each data source (data source = third party API), each class contains the same functions with the same exact signatures - `getData` and `convertData`, and return a callback with the results.

I've also created a module that creates many `user` mocks, since each user context returns different data (meaning, a user object is fed into `getData`, which uses certain `user` properties in order to determine what data should be returned).

The way I wanted to test this was to create numerous mocks, then run the functions for each. This is what I've got so far:

```
// Data sources to iterate over. Each is a class instance acquired through "require".
var dataSources = [
    source1,
    source2,
    source3,
    source4
];

describe('getData', function() {       
    this.timeout(10000);
    describe('per data source,', function() {
        context('standard call', function() {

            // Associative array to hold the data returned, a key for each data source.
            var finalResults = {};

            // Iterate over all data sources
            _.forEach(dataSources, function(dataSource) {

                // Generate user mocks
                var users = userMocks(10);

                // Iterate over all users. 
                _.forEach(users, function (user) {

                    // Call each data source with each of the users.
                    // Numbers of calls to make - (users * data-sources), so in this case - 10*4.
                    dataSource.getData(user, function (err, data) {
                        if (err) return done(err);

                        // Convert the data returned to my format
                        dataSource.convertData(data, function (err, processedData) {
                            if (err) return done(err);

                            // Populate finalResults with converted data from each source
                            if (finalResults[dataSource.sourceName]) {
                                finalResults[dataSource.sourceName] = finalResults[dataSource.sourceName].concat(processedData);
                            } else {
                                finalResults[dataSource.sourceName] = processedData;
                            }
                        });
                    });
                });
            });

            it('should return something', function(done) {
                _.forEach(finalResults.keys, function(key) {
                    expect(finalResults[key]).to.not.be.empty;
                    expect(finalResults[key].length).to.be.greaterThan(0);
                });
                setTimeout(function() {
                    done();
                }, 10000);
            })
        });
     });
});
```

});`

This works (or at least the test passes when the query is valid, which is what I wanted), but it's cumbersome and (so very) far from elegant or effective, specifically the usage of timeout rather than using promises, async of some sort, or maybe a different alternative I'm not yet familiar with.

Since most of the resources I found (http://alanhollis.com/node-js-testing-a-node-js-api-with-mocha-async-and-should/, https://developmentnow.com/2015/02/05/make-your-node-js-api-bulletproof-how-to-test-with-mocha-chai-and-supertest/, https://justinbellamy.com/testing-async-code-with-mocha/, just to name a few) discuss direct API testing rather than specific async functions, I would love to get some input/best practices tips from more experienced Noders.

Comment: It's rather easy to spin up and tear down http srevers in node.js. Instead of data mocks, create lots of lightweight "mock" data servers that perform tests on the request data, as well as serve out "mock" data to your app. You can even share javascript executing context between the server and the test code! This will make your tests move on the scale from "unit" to "integration" a little bit, but will make things like this a lot cleaner.

Comment: @lxe I totally agree, didn't go into too much detail but that's what i'm basically doing, the end result is an array of users, but i'm using a service in order to do it (which is being used elsewhere as well). The next step, which is to test my own API that's consolidating all these third party calls, will be much like what you're describing. Really appreciate the input!

Answer (score 0):

You need to know when bunch of asynchronous operations complete. Elegant way to test that is to use promises and promise aggregation:

```
Promise.all([ promise1, promise2, promise3 ]).then(function(results) {
  // all my promises are fulfilled here, and results is an array of results
});
```

Wrap your `dataSources` into a promises using [bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api-reference.html). You don't need to modify tested code self, bluebird provides convenience method:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird')
var dataSources = [
    source1,
    source2,
    source3,
    source4
].map(Promise.promisifyAll);
```

Use newly promisified functions to create promise for each call:

```
   context('standard call', function() {
        var finalResults = {};
        var promiseOfResults = datasources.map(function(dataSource) {
            var users = userMocks(10);
            // Promise.all will take an array of promises and return a promise that is fulfilled then all of promises are
            return Promise.all( users.map(function(user) {
                // *Async functions are generated by bluebird, via Promise.promisifyAll
                return dataSource.getDataAsync(user)
                     .then(dataSource.convertDataAsync)
                     .then(function(processedData) {
                        if (finalResults[dataSource.sourceName]) {
                            finalResults[dataSource.sourceName] = finalResults[dataSource.sourceName].concat(processedData);
                        } else {
                            finalResults[dataSource.sourceName] = processedData;
                        }
                    });
            });
        });
        // promiseOfResults consists now of array of agregated promises
        it('should return something', function(done) {
            // Promise.all agregates all od your 'datasource' promises and is fulfilled when all of them are
            // You don't need the promise result here, since you agegated finalResults yourself
            return Promise.all( promiseOfResults ).then(function() {
                _.forEach(finalResults.keys, function(key) {
                    expect(finalResults[key]).to.not.be.empty;
                    expect(finalResults[key].length).to.be.greaterThan(0);
                });
                done();
            });
        });
```

Rest of your test should use same `Promise.all( promiseOfResults )`, unless you need new set of results.

Comment: excuse the inexperience, but does it matter if the functions are already built to use callbacks? Would passing in a simple error handling function satisfy the promise regardless?

Comment: @CodeBender Bluebird's promisification requires function/object it works on to have `callback(err,result)`, so yes, it does matter. In other words, you won't get generated `getDataAsync` if your `getData` is not built do use callback. It is possible to make test toce that test code without promises, but it will be significantly larger and much less readable.

Comment: I don't think my question was clear enough - not really sure where `getDataAsync` and `convertDataAsync` came from - could you please elaborate on those? Is that just a placeholder for my `getData` and `convertData` functions or actual functions which are auto-generated, or maybe functions that should be added to each data source class?

Comment: @CodeBender These are actual auto-generated functions. They are created by call to `Promise.promisifyAll`.

Comment: Unfortunately getting an error because i have `callback(null, data)` within the `getData` function itself (getting a `uncaughtException: callback is not a function` error. What am I missing? Can't find any useful documentation on the bluebird library.

Comment: @CodeBender Promisification docs are here: http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisifyall.html . Call off `callback(null,data)` is perfectly normal; are you calling `getDataAsync` in your test code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104785/discussion-between-koder-and-codebender).